Expected to find a valid target. TargetId=T4 in react-dnd
Error Stack:
main.9b3f8a1a.js:187 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Expected to find a valid target. targetId=T11
at r (https://licalhost:8080.com/static/js/main.9b3f8a1a.js:187:2417428)
at Y.canDropOnTarget (https://loclahost:8080static/js/main.9b3f8a1a.js:187:2476109)
at https://localhost8080.com/static/js/main.9b3f8a1a.js:187:2463757
at Array.some (<anonymous>)
at C.handleTopDragEnter (https://localhost:8080.com/static/js/main.9b3f8a1a.js:187:2463735)

I am using react-dnd to drag and drop between fields but encountered the above issue
export const DraggableField = (props) => {
  const {
    field,
    section,
    sectionIndex,
    rowIndex,
    children,
    handleDeleteField,
    saveFields
  } = props;

  const { projectForm, schema, actions: { updateSchema } } = ProviderV2();

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const projectId = projectForm.projectID;

  const dragDropRef = useRef(null);

  const applyClass = () => {
    let classList = [styles['field'];
    return classList.join(' ');
  };

  const [, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: DRAG_TYPES.FIELD,
    hover: (item, _) => {
      if (!dragDropRef.current) return;
      const dragIndex = item.rowIndex;
      const hoverIndex = rowIndex;
      if (dragIndex === hoverIndex) return;
      const fields = [...schema[sectionIndex]?.fields]; 
      const dragged = fields[dragIndex];
      fields.splice(dragIndex, 1);
      fields.splice(hoverIndex, 0, dragged); 
      saveFields(hoverIndex, dragged[0]);
      updateSchema((prevSchema) => {
        return prevSchema.map((data) => {
          if (data.id.toLowerCase() === section.id.toLowerCase()) {
            return {
              ...data,
              fields: fields
            }
          }
          return data;
        })
      })
      item.rowIndex = hoverIndex;
    }
  });

  const [, drag] = useDrag({
    type: DRAG_TYPES.FIELD,
    item: () => ({ rowIndex }),
  });

  drag(drop(dragDropRef));
  const sectionType = section?.sectionType ?? section?.type;
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div ref={dragDropRef}>
          {children}
          <div />
        </div>
        <div>
          <ButtonGroup sx={{ borderColor: 'gray' }} variant="outlined">
            <Button
              onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>
              <Pencil />
            </Button>
            <Button
              onClick={() => handleDeleteField(field.id)}
            >
              <DeleteIconComponent />
            </Button>
          </ButtonGroup>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

Please let me know if you need any more details
I was expecting if accept is used in useDrop we should not deal with any targetId but getting this error only. The latest version of react-dnd I am using is 15+.
When the page is rendered initially, all drop targets are registered with a targetId. In valid cases, only the positions of the targetIds are updated, and no new targetIds are created. However, in scenarios where the delete icon is disabled, a new dynamic targetId is generated. This can replace an existing valid targetId during drag-and-drop operations, causing issues when attempting to swap items. The swap fails because the old, valid targetId is no longer valid, leading to errors.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

What is the complete error message and stacktrace? Please [edit] the post to include them as formatted and readable text instead of images that are not accessible. Is the problem the drag(drop(dragDropRef)); in the function body as an unintentional side-effect?

This is the error stack @drew
main.9b3f8a1a.js:187 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Expected to find a valid target. targetId=T11
at r (https://licalhost:8080.com/static/js/main.9b3f8a1a.js:187:2417428)
at Y.canDropOnTarget (https://loclahost:8080static/js/main.9b3f8a1a.js:187:2476109)
at https://localhost8080.com/static/js/main.9b3f8a1a.js:187:2463757
at Array.some (<anonymous>)
at C.handleTopDragEnter (https://localhost:8080.com/static/js/main.9b3f8a1a.js:187:2463735)


Hmm, that wasn't very helpful at all. Think you could try again in a non-production build so the stacktrace spits out more meaningful names? Or see if you can create a running CodeSandbox demo that reproduces the issue that readers can inspect live?
